# FFMPEG: Can not free AVPacket when decode H264 stream?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, decode, h.264

I'm using FFMPEG to decode H264 stream, my code is below

```
AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = NULL;
AVCodecContext  *pCodecCtx = NULL;
AVFrame         *pFrame = NULL;
AVPacket        packet;
packet.data = NULL;

pFormatCtx = avformat_alloc_context();  
avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, videoStreamPath, NULL, NULL);
liveHeader.pCodecCtx = pFormatCtx->streams[videoStreamIndex]->codec;

int  bytesDecoded = 0;
int  frameFinished = 0;
while (true)
{
    while (packet.size > 0)
    {
        // Decode the next chunk of data
        bytesDecoded = avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame,
            &frameFinished, &packet);

        // Was there an error?
        if (bytesDecoded < 0)
        {
            printf(strErr, "Error while decoding frame\n");
            commonGlobal->WriteRuntimeRecLogs(strErr);
            return RS_NOT_OK;
        }

        packet.size -= bytesDecoded;
        packet.data += bytesDecoded;
        if (frameFinished)
        {               
            //av_free_packet(&packet); //(free 1)
            return RS_OK;
        }
        // Did we finish the current frame? Then we can return
    }
    do
    {
        try
        {
            int ret = av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet);
            if (ret < 0)
            {
                char strErr[STR_LENGTH_256];
                if (ret == AVERROR_EOF || (pFormatCtx->pb && pFormatCtx->pb->eof_reached))
                {
                    sprintf(strErr, "Error end of file line %d", __LINE__);
                }
                if (pFormatCtx->pb && pFormatCtx->pb->error)
                {
                    sprintf(strErr, "Error end of file line %d", __LINE__);
                }
                packet.data = NULL;
                return RS_NOT_OK;
            }
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            packet.data = NULL;
            return RS_NOT_OK;
        }
    } while (packet.stream_index != videoStreamIndex);
}

//av_free_packet(&packet); //(free 2)
```

The problem is I don't know how to free memory of `packet` correctly.

I have tried to delete packet's data by calling one of two places `av_free_packet(&packet); (free 1)` and `av_free_packet(&packet); (free 2)`. And the result is the application was crashed with the message `"Heap Corruption..."`

If I do not free the `packet`, the memory leak is occur.

Note that the above code is successful when decode `H264` stream, the main problem is memory leak and crashed when I try to free the `packet`

Someone can show me the problems in my code.

Many thanks,

T&T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`av_free_packet` will clear your packet data, the same pointer that was allocated inside `av_read_frame`. But you changed it in `packet.data += bytesDecoded;` => crash.

Several advices:

- No need to call `av_init_packet` if the first use of your packet is `av_read_frame` (it is done inside this function). But if you keep your code, you need it in order to initialize `packet.size` to 0 (tested, but not initialized the first time)
- Call `av_free_packet` each time you are done with the packet data, only when the decode is successful. In your code, it means you must call it after `avcodec_decode_video2`, even if the frame is not finished.
- Once your packed is decoded (i.e. `avcodec_decode_video2` is ok, no matter if `frameFinished` is true or false), you can free it. No need to keep it and change data pointer. The process is "read packet, decode it, free it. read next packet, decode it, free it.". (Note that this does not apply to audio packets).

I suggest simplify your main loop by something like (read first, decode after):

```
while(true)
{
    // Step 1: Read packet
    while(true)
    {
        av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet);

        // todo: Error handling

        if(packet.stream_index != videoStreamIndex)
        {
            av_free_packet(&packet);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    } while (packet.stream_index != videoStreamIndex);

    // Step 2/3: Decode and free
    avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet);
    av_free_packet(&packet);

    // todo: Error handling and checking frameFinished if needed
    // Of course, if you need to use the packet now, move the av_free_packet() after this
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize your packet before usage as following:

```
AVPacket        packet;
av_init_packet(&packet);
```

Also your not deleting your `AVFormatContext` instance.

```
avformat_free_context(pFormatCtx);
```

Comment: Thank you. This code is not complete, actually I have call av_close_input_file(pFormatCtx) instead of avformat_free_context(pFormatCtx); Is there any problem?